# Disable 'Always' in Android View and SendTo Intent popup

Tags: android, android-intent

I have intent-filters defined in my app for `action.SENDTO` and `action.VIEW` as follows:

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/myString">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="my.url"
                android:scheme="http" />

            ..etc..
```

The intents work as expected, but is there a way to only allow the users to select the 'Just Once' option in the popup and to remove or disable the 'Always' option?

Reason: When my users share from my app, if they have selected 'Always' they end up in a loop as what they are sharing matches the 'my.url' string, so automatically launches the intent again rather than giving the share options.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. It's a part of the OS implementation, and has nothing to do with your app. But the fact that it's starting to loop means that you implemented the logic in your app incorrectly. You should be intercepting that intent and processing it, not re-sending it

Comment: @user496854 the loop is legitimate. The app receives a URL, processes it and the user chooses to share that URL. Because the app can also further process the processed URL it is legitimate for the app to receive the URL again a second (and third etc) time, but if the user has selected to always open with the app they have then lost the opportunity to share the processed URL elsewhere.

Comment: And that's why having that loop is absolutely the wrong way to handle it. Circular logic is never the right approach. You would need to create a custom scheme for your app, so it's the only one that can receive it's own intents, and then use the common intents if you want to send them out for other apps to process

Comment: @user496854 Sorry, you are wrong. The app processes plain Amazon links and Amazon affiliate links and generates Amazon affiliate links. It therefore needs to be able to receive links in intents. The app then allows the user to share these links. By their very nature these links are the type that it also needs to be able to receive.

Comment: @user496854 Also, while it may be the case that what I am looking for is not possible, the share popup itself is "part of the OS implementation" yet you can control whether your app is listed in that popup by including the relevant `intent-filter`s in your manifest, so to suggest that an app has no control over how it interacts with OS functions is misleading.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it -- I'm unequivocally stating it: neither your app, nor any other app has any control over that pop-up. You get to 'advertise' that you can handle a specific intent, and the OS decides to include you as one of the options. That's not the same as having any control over it. So as a strict answer to your OP is definitely a **NO**. However, you're still missing my point that what you're trying to do is a terrible design decision. The actual solution to your problem is to re-design it for a better workflow, and no amount of arguing on your part will change that

Comment: @user496854 Well, you are CERTAINLY wrong on the app design point, so why should I believe you 100% on the question of 'advertising' to the OS that my app can handle the intent but should not be allowed to be set as the default. I'm not going to argue with you, I'll just wait to see if someone less sanctimonious responds with information that is actually useful, even if it does point to information that confirms what you are merely SUGGESTING at this point.